# Rails asset precompiling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets, precompile, bootstrap-sass

I am trying to set up Rails 5 with `bootstrap-sass`.

app/assets/application.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

config/initializers/assets.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(*.js *.css)
```

I get following error: `Sass::SyntaxError ... Undefined variable: "$alert-padding"`.
This is because of `*.css` in `precompile`.

But if I leave only `%w(*.js)` Rails will still compile my controller specific stylesheets. I am happy because it will but why will it do this?

Comment: Why are you compiling everything (rather than just the manifests(s) ?

Comment: @FrederickCheung, I wanna use controller-specific assets. So, in manifests (like `application.js`, right?) I dont include all tree. Is there a better way to do this?